# Measuring and analyzing survey data

Tags: survey

I am in charge of creating a new survey for a food education/cooking class program for middle and high school students. The overall goal of the program is to improve overall knowledge and confidence when it comes to cooking and making healthier choices. The survey aims to evaluate the program impact and behavior changes. I am unsure of the best survey method and statistical analysis for a program like this. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think this question is rather too broad in its current form. Do you think you can narrow it down a little?

Answer (score 1):

I used to work at a research analyst for a grant funded program at local MS/HSs. Usually, with a survey like this, I would recommend using Qualtrics (https://www.qualtrics.com/). If you're not tech savvy, it'll simplify the data collection process and analysis.

You can create a free account that accepts up to about 1500 responses. You can then export the data to Excel or whatever.

> The survey aims to evaluate the program impact and behavior changes. I am unsure of the best survey method and statistical analysis for a program like this. Any thoughts?

As for the survey itself, I recommend reviewing what exactly you want to show/prove with the results, and how that should be measured. Also, if there is an intervention program being implemented, it would behoove you to conduct a pre- and post- survey with the same students for comparable results.

For the analysis, I would keep things simple with means and proportions. Don't over complicate the solution to the problem.

I can adjust this response based on any specific questions you may have. Feel free to ask anything!